# Yammer REST API for create status with topic and get back the topic Id

Tags: javascript, status, yammer

i want to create yammer status using php and javascript. this is my sample code for that-

```
    <script type="text/javascript" data-app-id="client-id" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js"></script>
    <span id="yammer-login"></span>
    <script> 
        $(function(){

            yam.connect.loginButton('#yammer-login', function (resp) { 
                if (resp.authResponse) {
                    yam.platform.request({
                        url: "messages.json",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: {
                            "body" : "Message body",
                            "group_id": "4728511", //group id
                            "topic1": "TestTopic1",
                            "og_url": "http://google.com"
                        },
                        success: function (res) { //print message response information to the console
                            alert("The request was successful.");
                            console.dir(res);
                            yam.platform.request({
                                url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/search.json",
                                method: "GET",
                                data: {
                                    "search" : "TestTopic1"
                                },
                                success: function (data) { //print message response information to the console
                                    alert("The request was successful.");
                                    console.dir(data);
                                },
                                error: function (data) {
                                    alert("There was an error with the request.");
                                    console.log(data)
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        error: function (res) {
                            alert("There was an error with the request.");
                            console.dir(res);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

The status is updated on yammer but its showing error, also i did not get the topic id.
so how can i correct it..??

thanks in advance

Comment: If you clarify the error message you're receiving it would help everyone answer your question easier.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your second call to search.json is the culprit. When using the JS SDK you should be calling the REST resources directly instead of putting in the URL (like: www.yammer.com or api.yammer.com).

You've done this successfully with your first call to messages.json, but should update your second call to this:

```
yam.platform.request({
   url: "search.json",
   method: "GET",
   data: {
     "search" : "TestTopic1"
   },
   success: function (data) { //print message response information to the console
     alert("The request was successful.");
     console.dir(data);
   },
   error: function (data) {
     alert("There was an error with the request.");
     console.log(data)
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply, actually when my first call where status is creating its not going in success function, instead its going in error function and when m printing 

          'console.dir(res);' 

its showing  
[dropbox_error_image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1wrg9144dr42cbc/yammer.JPG?dl=0)